# How to enforce a derived type for a method that is implemented from abstract?

Tags: c#

My abstract class has a method that is abstract like this:

```
 public abstract void Run(BaseType baseType);
```

And now in my derived class which has to implement this function, i want it to only accept a specific derived type from `BaseType`

So it would have:

```
public override void Run(DerivedType derivedType){}
```

Is there any way to enforce this at all ?

Currently i have to do:

```
public override void Run(BaseType baseType) {
   if(!(baseType is DerivedType)) {
       // throw exception
   }
}
```

It's not very strict with enforcing the type - i was wondering if there is a way to do so without the need to constantly add a type check ?

Comment: I think at design time you cannot enforce it. At runtime with an actual instance you have to check the type only once and remember that.

Comment: `public new void Run(DerivedType derivedType) { base.Run(derivedType); }` if I understand what you want?

Comment: @vasily.sib `base.Run` won't work since the base method is abstract - there's no body to it. But i could try it. Does that count as implementing the abstract method though ? Otherwise it's still not every enforceable.

Comment: @WDUK Being blunt, you might have more success re-architecting this part of your application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've sometimes used this pattern:

```
public interface IHandler
{
    void Run();
}

public abstract class BaseHandler<TObj> : IHandler
    where TObj: BaseType
{
    protected readonly TObj _obj {get;set;}

    public BaseHandler(TObj obj)
    {
        this._obj = obj;
    }

    public abstract void Run();
}

public class DerivedHandler : BaseHandler<DerivedType>
{
    public DerivedHandler(DerivedType obj) : base(obj)
    {
    }

    public override void Run()
    {
        // do stuff with base._obj
    }
}

public class HandlerService
{
    public IHandler CreateHandler<TObj>(TObj obj)
    {
        // Depending on your DI container, you could resolve this automatically from the container
        if (typeof(TObj) == typeof(DerivedType))
        {
            return new DerivedHandler(obj);
        }
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

This allows you to define a specific "handler" for each derived type, and then access it through a common interface.

The idea is that you instantiate a specific handler for the object, and then methods like `Run()` operate on that object. You can then resolve a handler through the service.

I'll fill in some more info later when I have time.

Answer (score 1):

You want the language to do something that it really shouldn't. You want a covariant argument, which  violates the Liskov Substitution Principle: It makes the implementation of the abstract class not usable in every situation where the abstract base class is usable. This is the whole point of abstract base classes to begin with.
Although it could make sense to have a covariant return type (returning a more derived type then the abstract methods specifies) the language also prevents you to do that.

Comment: What would be a clean setup for it then ? Where i need the method implemented to make sure its there, but also need the type check first? When making a lot of these - forgetting to type check can be problematic in large software and easy to forget.

Comment: @WDUK What is the problem you're trying to solve? Since you've come up against this problem, I feel that there's probably a better way to solve your business concern which avoids this programming problem entirely.

Comment: I want all my derived classes to have the run method (so i use abstract to guarantee it), but since these derived classes link to different systems of which have different parameters for their initialise methods, the `override Run` method, there for, needs to accept different derived types depending on what system they link to.